# How to find the matched word count of "abc" in two columns in excel?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find the matched word count of abc between two columns in excel.
In the below excel sample snapshot, the word abc of column1 is matched thrice with the word abc of column2. So, I need the count to be given as 3.

Can anyone please help me out in framing the formula in excel ?

[image: sample]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `COUNTIFS` formula will do:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A5,"abc",B1:B5,"abc")
```